# Is it possible to use a template variable in Django dictsort filter?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to sort a list with blog titles using a drop-down button with sorting options:

```
...
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'profile-sorted' passed_user.pk 'title' %}">alphabet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'profile-sorted' passed_user.pk '-post_date' %}">post date</a>
</div>
```

The corresponding urls are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('user/<int:pk>', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('user/<int:pk>/sorted/<str:sorting>', views.profile, name='profile-sorted'),
]
```

The view:

```
def profile(request, pk, sorting='title'):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'passed_user': user, 'sorting': sorting}
    return render(request, 'feed/profile.html', context=context)
```

The template part with list sorting:

```
{% for blog in passed_user.blog_set.all|dictsort:"{{ sorting }}" %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h6 class="mb-0">{{ forloop.counter }}.
        <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.pk %}">{{ blog }}</a>
      </h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

When 'sorting' variable is used here: `dictsort:"{{ sorting }}"`, the list becomes empty. However, when I just put 'title', the list is sorted as expected, by blog title.

I tried to check 'sorting' variable itself in the template by just typing `{{ sorting }}` and it returns the correct string value when one of the drop-down links is clicked. And I have not found anything useful in the Django Github source code for dictsort function.

Does anybody know if it is possible at all to put a variable as a sorting key in dictsort? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Business logic should not be done at template level, it should be done at `view` level

Comment: @Zilay thank you, would you say it is better to create a custom template tag/filter with sorting functionality in this case? What could be improved here in your opinion?

Comment: I mean, you should do all of your sorting stuff in view and the template is a presentation layer that should only show the data.

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out the solution, the mistake was very silly: curly brackets should not be used with if, for, etc. in a template, so just removing {{ }} around 'sorting' did the trick!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).